# Shopware 6 use route in cms-text-element/layout

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I need to add the following button via text-editor.
`<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-url="path('frontend.cms.page', { id: config('core.basicInformation.contactPage')" href="path('frontend.cms.page', { id: config('core.basicInformation.contactPage')">`

But the route can't be resolved. By klicking on the button I get the following erroe message:

> No route found for "GET http://.../path('frontend.cms.page',%20%7B%20id:%20config('core.basicInformation.contactPage')" (from "http://.../")

Does anyone know if there is a way to use routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Twig functions inside the text-editor.

However it is possible by directly using the ID like this:

```
<a href="/widgets/cms/a1fe36fee44f41d3a6df0472b0bb49af" title="Contact us" data-toggle="modal" data-url="/widgets/cms/a1fe36fee44f41d3a6df0472b0bb49af">Contact us</a>
```

You can get the ID from the contact page from the navbar in your browser:

[image: Get ID from navbar browser]